# Flex: Panel container loses borderSkin (embedded swf) when scrollbars appear

Tags: apache-flex, panel

I've been asking around and googling like crazy, but can't figure this one out.
I have a panel in a flex-AIR app with a borderSkin - an @Embed swf symbol. Everything looks good till the panel has enough children added to merit a scrollbar, at which point the borderSkin disappears, leaving only the default background color. Remove the children and the borderskin comes back. The swf symbol uses scale9 grids.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance, Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

I did find the answer from a friend.
Apparently, the panel's background color disappears automatically when a custom borderskin is applied. However, when scrollbars are used, that background reappears - white being the default color - and fills the entire panel. Setting the panel's background alpha to 0 solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly cheated. 
I put my panel in a box and turned to off the scroll policy of my panel.
Hope it could help.
Cdkey22